# Installing JenkinsX on Kubernetes Cluster - Failing compliance tests

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I ran the jx compliance tests, and now when I run the command to get the results, I get this :

```
FAILED BeforeSuite Kubernetes e2e suite
```

I really don't know what I'm meant to do with that information, it doesn't really seem to tell me what I can do to remedy the situation.

Comment: The same issue. Did you resolve it?